# which function is this jmpq line calling? how to figure out?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly, att

what does the line

```
jmpq   400a06 <rand@plt+0x416>
```

mean? I know there is a shared library function called, but how can i figure out which function?

Comment: It's not a function call, it's a _branch within_ a function, and the disassembler already gave you the name ... `rand()`.

Comment: @FrankH. it's unlikely to be in `rand()`, due to the large offset and the `plt` section. It's just that the nearest known symbol is `rand@plt` so the disassembler prints the offset to that. The `.text` section typically follows the `plt` and if you don't have symbols then this is what happens.